# How to add Checkbox List from GET api React-Native-Fetch-Blob?

Tags: react-native, react-native-fetch-blob

i want to add checkbox list data from GET API React-Native-Fetch-Blob. have any solution?

this is my code checkbox

```
class....{
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    name: false,
  };
}
render(){
  return(
   <CheckBox checked={this.state.name}/>
      <Text style={{marginLeft: 20}}>List Checkbox 1</Text>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact requirement ? Can you be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a way to fetch data from fetchBlob:

```
RNFetchBlob.fetch('GET', 'API', {
    Authorization : 'access-token',
    // more headers  ..
  })
  // when response status code is 200
  .then((res) => {
    let json = res.json()
  })
  // Status code is not 200
  .catch((errorMessage, statusCode) => {
    // error handling
  })
```

After all this pass data to the checkbox..

Cheers :)